# OpenSSL PHP to JavaScript (node)

Tags: php, node.js, encryption, openssl

I am converting an encryption script from PHP to JavaScript and am struggling...

The [node.js cipher documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createcipheriv_algorithm_key_iv) is as follows:

> `crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, key, iv)`
>   Creates and returns a cipher object, with the given algorithm, key and iv.

The [PHP openssl-encrypt documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.openssl-encrypt.php):

> `string openssl_encrypt ( string $data , string $method , string $password [, bool $raw_output = false [, string $iv = "" ]] )`

PHP uses a *password* and and *iv*. Node only uses a *password* when **no** IV is used, otherwise you have to provide a *key* and an *iv*.

How would I convert my PHP function to node, when I'm using both, the *password* and *iv*.

I'm also unclear on what exactly the *key* represents... the node documentation states that the *key* and *iv* are calculated if only a *password* is provided.. is this what PHP does? If so, what does it do when I provide a *password* and an *iv*? Does it use the *password* as *key*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [user comments](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php#104438) in the PHP documentation, it seems the `$password` parameter in PHP is actually the encryption key, and not an actual password. This seems consistent with [OpenSSL docs](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/enc.html), which state that you use *either* a key and initialization vector, *or* use a password from which the key and IV are algorithmically derived, but you never provide a password and IV together.

**Example:**

```
<?php echo openssl_encrypt('foobar', 'aes-256-cbc', 'password', false, 'abcdefghijklmnop');
// prints CUigVN+6jU24E2FdfmmmTw==

#!/bin/bash
echo -n foobar | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -e -K 70617373776F7264 -iv 6162636465666768696A6B6C6D6E6F70 -nosalt -a
// prints CUigVN+6jU24E2FdfmmmTw==
```

The gotcha is probably that you need to provide the key and IV to `openssl` in hexadecimal.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I still didn't manage to get PHP to produce the same results as: `openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -e -pass pass:pass -nosalt -a`